video conference tile view resize listener
I work on a video conferencing app, and want to re-write the logic for the tile / gallery view in our call room.
Basically, we want to make the video call participant's divs as big as possible (either stacked or side-to-side), to fill a given parent div. They will always be a particular ratio (4:3).
how are people doing this?
are there any libraries or open-source projects for this?
I hope this question makes sense!
I really like how google meet are doing it, I think they are using translate3d.
Animations would also be great.
Thanks
We have a solution at the moment, a mutation observer wrapped in a directive in our angular app. However we are experiencing some jankiness and strange behaviour when users enter and exit the room, and other elements come on screen, changing the layout.

Hi Joseph. Welcome to stackoverflow! Please can you update your question to include the code that's janky? See how to create a minimal reproducible example, how to ask and What types of questions should I avoid asking. This question is possibly a bit too open-ended to be suitable for this site. Hope this helps and best wishes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
